# Segment fault while convert cvPoint[][] to cvPoint** in openCV

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, opencv

I tried to use cvFillPoly() and cvPolyline() but it doesn't work.
Please help me what i did wrong?

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main() {

    IplImage *background;

    background = cvCreateImage( cvSize(800,600) , IPL_DEPTH_8U , 3 );

    CvPoint listpoint[][4] = {
        {cvPoint(35,70),cvPoint(160,34),cvPoint(245,570),cvPoint(23,700)},
        {cvPoint(563,341),cvPoint(20,80),cvPoint(320,40)},
        {cvPoint(350,470),cvPoint(700,599),cvPoint(400,400)}
    };

    int _npts[3] = {4,3,3};

    cvFillPoly( background , listpoint , _npts , 1 , cvScalar(255,255,255) );

    cvNamedWindow( "Drawing Things" , CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( "Drawing Things" , background );

    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvReleaseImage( &background );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Drawing Things" );

    return 0;
}
```

And this is error: (on Qt creator)

```
 cannot convert 'CvPoint (*)[4]' to 'CvPoint**' for argument '2' to 'void cvPolyLine(CvArr*, CvPoint**, const int*, int, int, CvScalar, int, int, int)'
 cvPolyLine( BasedImage , listpoint , numberpoint , 1 , 0 , cvScalar(255,255,255) , 0 , CV_AA );
                                                                                              ^
```

Comment: please use opencv's c++ api, not the deprecated c-api.

Comment: thankyou. i see, but i really don't know what i did wrong there! :v

Comment: An array is not a pointer. In particular, an array of arrays is not an array of pointers.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a compiler error. Why tiitled as  segmentation fault ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the difference between `int A[4][5]` and `int**B`: the first has 20 elements consecutively in memory (starting with `A`) and the other has *pointers* to `int` arrays in memory.

In other words - in `B` you get a list of arrays - each one located at a different memory location, each can have a different size. When you look at the data in the memory location of `B` itself you see a pointer to the first array.

In `A` - it's just a convenient shortcut: You can think of `int A[4][5]` as `int real_A[20]`, and each time you do `A[i][j]` you're actually doing (in the assembly code) `real_A[i*5+j]`

When you look at the data in the memory location of `A` itself you see the data of `A[0][0]`.

So when you pass listpoint to openCV, it looks at the data in the `listpoint` location in memory (which is actually a `cvPoint`) and interprets it as a pointer in memory, getting garbage location and segmentation fault :)

Edit - try this to see for yourself:

```
int A[4][5];
cout << A<<" "<<&A[0]<<" "<<&A[0][0]<<endl;
```

You'll get the same value 3 times!

Comment: thanks so much. 
i have just realized that if I try to access a memory at listpoint[1] . My intention is access to the second polygon, but indeed, i can only access the second point of array listpoin contain 10 elements consecutively.
...
That is stupid mistake!